# Insert record in access table using VB

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a record into an Access table (hyperlinks) and the field "link" should be set to "u:\directory here\"
I have tried

```
docmd.runsql "insert into hyperlinks (link."U:\directory here\")"
```

and get errors, I tried ' instead of " and I tried without the quotes, all end in error with not specification as to what is wrong.

Comment: *"error with not specification as to what is wrong"* - What does the error message say?  "get errors" isn't very specific.  Read the error messages, they're trying to tell you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
docmd.runsql "insert into hyperlinks (link) values ('U:\directory here\')"
```

The syntax of an MS Access SQL `insert` statement can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql).

Comment: Ok beat me to it - i'll delete my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If your field is of type `Hyperlink` (rather than of type `text`), your SQL needs to use the following format:

```
Display Text#Link Path#Sub address#optional screen tip#
```

If you just want the link path (e.g. `https://google.com`), simply enclose it with the `#`:

```
INSERT INTO tHyperlinks (path) VALUES ("#https://google.com#")
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/use-hyperlink-fields-ms-access-effectively/)

Personally, I don't like to use the `Hyperlink` data type in Access: I find it's easier to use a simple text field, and generate a hyperlink in a form.

Additionally, I would recommend against using `DoCmd.RunSQL`. Whenever  you use this method, the user will see a confirmation message (allowing them to cancel the update), unless you turn it off:
[image: action query confirmation]

To turn off this confirmation, you'd have to something like the following:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL yourSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Even worse, if the user has changed their options to not show these confirmations by default, you'll show the confirmation (when they've specifically said they don't want to view them).

It is far better to use the `Database.Execute` method in the DAO library:

```
Dim db as DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute yourSQL, dbFailOnError
```

The user won't get a confirmation message (regardless of their client settings), and with the `dbFailOnError`, an error will be generated if the record isn't added, which will give you nice detailed information (the error below is when I deleted a parenthesis):

[image: db.execute error]

You can then perform error handling.

For more information on `DoCmd.RunSQL` vs. `Database.Execute`, see [these](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/docmdrunsql-currentdbe-t1953226.html) [links](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/10895_3505836_2/Executing-SQL-Statements-in-VBA-Code.htm).

Official Microsoft Docs pages you might find useful:

- [Hyperlink data type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c#refhyperlink)
- [DoCmd.RunSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql)
- [Database.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao)